# Replace an element in a pandas dataframe column if present in another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

There are two dataframes given by:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha': [10, 22, 10, 45, 44, 21, 62, 84, 32, 97, 38]})
test = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha': [10, 97, 32, 34, 44, 76, 49]})
```

If each value of test is **not** present in train, then the test values should be replaced with -1.

Expected output: `[10, 97, 32, -1, 44, -1, -1]` since 34, 76 and 49 are not present in train.

What I tried:

```
for x in test.Alpha:
    if x not in train.Alpha:
        test = test.Alpha.replace(x, -1)
```

Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `isin`:

```
test.loc[~test.Alpha.isin(train.Alpha), 'Alpha'] = -1
```

Output of `test`:

```
   Alpha
0     10
1     97
2     32
3     -1
4     44
5     -1
6     -1
```